# Using Pulumi to setup EventBridge cron for AWS Batch job

Tags: typescript, aws-event-bridge, pulumi, aws-batch

I'm trying to set up EventBridge to kick off a Batch job on a regular schedule.  I can deploy the batch job and the event rule through Pulumi, but when I attempt to deploy the EventTarget, I get this error:

> Creating EventBridge Target failed: ValidationException: Parameter(s)
> BatchParameters not supported for target: my_event_target-ca7145e.

I have set up an EventBridge for the same batch job through the AWS Console with no issue, and it runs fine.

Here is the code:

```
const eventBridgeDeadLetterQueue = new aws.sns.Topic("myEventBridge", {});

const myJob = new aws.batch.JobDefinition("my_job", {
    containerProperties: pulumi.interpolate `{
        "image": "${myImage}",
        "resourceRequirements": [
            {"type": "VCPU", "value": "1"},
            {"type": "MEMORY", "value": "4096"}
          ],
        "environment": [],
        "jobRoleArn": "${myEcsTaskRole.arn}",
        "executionRoleArn": "${myEcsTaskExecutionRole.arn}"
    }`,
    type: "container",
    timeout: {
        'attemptDurationSeconds': 30 * 60
    },
    platformCapabilities: ['FARGATE']
});

const myRule = new aws.cloudwatch.EventRule("myRule", {
    description: "Fire a batch job",
    scheduleExpression: "cron(30 15 * * ? *)"
});

//if I comment out this target, then I can successfully deploy
const myEventTarget = new aws.cloudwatch.EventTarget("my_event_target", {
    arn: eventBridgeDeadLetterQueue.arn,
    rule: myRule.name,
    inputPath: "$",  //I have also tried with input: "" and get the same error
    batchTarget: {
        jobDefinition: myJob.arn,
        jobName: "My Job Name"
    }
});
```

What am I doing wrong?  Thanks!